# OnLocationChanged is not called according to setFastestInterval() value

Tags: android, google-maps, location

OnLocationChanged is not always called according to setFastestInterval() value. I have set 1 minute for fastestInterval. But OnLocationChanged sometimes called after 2-3 minutes. I have checked this, while i was in moving state with my phone.

Below code & link I have tried, but didn't get any suitable solution. Is there any more suitable solution for this problem?

[I have tried this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988555/requesting-location-updates-more-often-than-5-seconds-android-fused-location)

Please see my code snippet below:-

```
private var mLocationProvider: FusedLocationProviderApi? = null

mLocationProvider = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest!!.interval = 1000 * 60 * 1  // 1 min
        mLocationRequest!!.fastestInterval = 1000 * 60 * 1 // 1 min
        mLocationRequest!!.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
```

Comment: Even somebody can give me any explanation, why this is happening?? It would be enough. Because I just have to send it to the client.

Comment: From LocationRequest docs: "All location requests are considered hints, and you may receive locations that are more/less accurate, and faster/slower than requested."